# Why unchanging arrow lengths in VectorPlot?

Tags: plotting, graphics, vector, scaling

I want to use `Manipulate` to plot a vector field that is scaled by a parameter. I use

```
Manipulate[VectorPlot[s {x, y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}], {s, -1, 1}]
```

I expect the length of the arrows to change continuously as $|s|$ changes. But instead the arrows always have the same length, independent of $s$. Only their direction changes when $s$ passes through 0.

I don't know if this is a bug or feature and I have to set `VectorScale` option to some value. I have looked at similar questions but haven't found an answer.

Comment: Why would they change in a manipulate as `s` varies if they don't change when plotted individually with differing independent values for `s`? `Table[VectorPlot[s {x, y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}], {s, -2, 2, .5}]`

Comment: I would imagine the arrows don't scale with absolute magnitude, but scale with relative magnitude with one another. `s` changes the magnitude globally across the plot, so the relative magnitude remains identical.

Comment: @user6014 The problem is that the arrows don't scale correctly, even in a single plot, i.e. `VectorPlot[{2 {x, y}, {x , y}}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 VectorPoints -> 5, VectorStyle -> {Red, Black}]` The first vector field is twice as long as the second, so I would expect a plot where the red arrows are twice as long as the black ones. But the plot only shows black arrows, which means that both arrow types are drawn with the same length. When one vector field is larger than the other, they should be displayed like that!

Answer (score 1):

When *Mathematica* has `VectorScale->Automatic` as default you scale it in one direction and *Mathematica* scales it back. Hence, you should work with this option, i.e. set a value.